# Snap "strict" applications under Ubuntu 20.04 can't access mounted folders under /home/user/?

Tags: permissions, mount, snap

looking for some insights here :

I cannot access mounted folders under /home/user/ from snap applications that do not enforce a -classic option (such as VLC & chromium).
I read in several places that "strict" snapped applications may not be able to access volumes mounted outside /media or /home/user/ but nowhere that volumes mounted within /home/user/ could also face permission issues.

The volumes are NTFS volumes mounted via a mount instruction in my root crontab (@reboot). Slack (which installed by default under snap --classic in my setup) can access them ok, for instance.

The setup is a dual boot Win10/Ubuntu 20.04.

Any idea what could be the issue ?

Answer (score 2):

It is up to the snap package to configure the permissions and have access either to the home folder, or to mounted devices. If you are a creator of a snap package, you can either enable permissions yourself, or you need to ask explicitly at the Snapcraft Forum to have it enabled it for you, for the specific package that you are creating.

These permissions are known as `interfaces` and you can find the full list at https://snapcraft.io/docs/supported-interfaces Those in the list that are *auto-connect*, it means that the packager can configure them themselves without asking for permission. But those that are not *auto-connect*, they have to visit https://forum.snapcraft.io/ and start a new thread asking to have it enabled for their package.

The two interfaces that you are asking, are `personal-files` and `removable-media`. Neither of these are *auto-connect*.

Here are the *interfaces* for the LibreOffice snap package:

```
$ snap interfaces libreoffice
Interface                 Plug                                Slot                             Notes
audio-playback            libreoffice:audio-playback          :audio-playback                  -
bluez                     libreoffice:bluez                   -                                -
content[gnome-3-28-1804]  libreoffice:gnome-3-28-1804         gnome-3-28-1804:gnome-3-28-1804  -
content[gtk-3-themes]     libreoffice:gtk-3-themes            gtk-common-themes:gtk-3-themes   -
content[icon-themes]      libreoffice:icon-themes             gtk-common-themes:icon-themes    -
content[sound-themes]     libreoffice:sound-themes            gtk-common-themes:sound-themes   -
cups-control              libreoffice:cups-control            :cups-control                    -
desktop                   libreoffice:desktop                 :desktop                         -
desktop-legacy            libreoffice:desktop-legacy          :desktop-legacy                  -
gsettings                 libreoffice:gsettings               :gsettings                       -
home                      libreoffice:home                    :home                            -
network                   libreoffice:network                 :network                         -
network-bind              libreoffice:network-bind            :network-bind                    -
opengl                    libreoffice:opengl                  :opengl                          -
pulseaudio                libreoffice:pulseaudio              :pulseaudio                      -
removable-media           libreoffice:removable-media         :removable-media                 -
screen-inhibit-control    libreoffice:screen-inhibit-control  :screen-inhibit-control          -
unity7                    libreoffice:unity7                  :unity7                          -
wayland                   libreoffice:wayland                 :wayland                         -
x11                       libreoffice:x11                     :x11                             -
```

`removable-media` is in the list, and [they asked for permission in this thread](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/request-auto-connection-of-removable-media-for-libreoffice/2660).

Therefore, if a snap package cannot open removable media, it is an issue of the packager not asking for permission for `removable-media`, or they  may have asked but it was declined.

Having said all that, you can bypass the snap package security by using the `--devmode` parameter. This gives you full access, as if you have installed a deb package. Note that you need to have some assurances that the snap package is OK, because anyone can create snap packages on the Snap Store and you will be disabling all security protection for this package.

Here is how to do that:

```
sudo snap install somesnappackage --devmode
```

Comment: Many thanks for your feedback.
To be more precise: I'm not developping any application, I'm trying to use ready snap applications which do not support --classic option such as chromium and VLC , in my particular environment having a NTFS mount under /home. Chromium, for instance has permission for removable media and /home, but yet it can not access files under my /home/user/<mounted folder>. I came back to a debian install of VLC, and may decide to do same thing with Chromium, but as more and more application seems to come with snap package I would rather understand where the problem lies..

Comment: Update on the issue: it turns out that I can access a mount --bind in /media/<user>/ from the snapped version of Chromium but the original mount point in /home/<user>/ cannot be accessed from the same Chromium, despite the fact that I can see these lines in snap connections chromium:
home                      chromium:home                           :home         
personal-files            chromium:chromium-config                :personal-files                  -

Comment: Yeah, bind mounts under `/media` is the expected way, and the snap service tries to play safe for you. You can always ask at https://forum.snapcraft.io/ if something looks amiss.

Comment: Yes, I'll stick to this workaround, even if I'm not too happy about multiplying mount points... anyways, thanks for your support and thanks for the tip about the snapcraft forum.

Comment: You want to update **interfaces** to **connections** that's the new term